# A href to a part of a page from another page

Tags: javascript, html

In the index page I have sections where I needed a href from a menu bar but there is a function that I needed to call to be able to href it.

```html
 <a href= "index.html#offers" onclick="switchTab()"><li class="link relative tl 
    block fl" id="link-3">Offers</li></a>
```

But this won't work from another pages because the function is in the index js so when I click on the offers on menu bar on the other pages it just take me to the index page and not to the offers part in the index page.

Is there a way to make it work on all the pages?

Comment: You'll need to include the javascript code in any page where you expect to have to call it.

Comment: i tried to link the index js to the other pages but it is destroying the the whole pages